# Heavside function (unit / step function) derivative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, calculus, perceptron

I am new to machine learning and am learning to program a Perceptron.

What is the derivative of the heavside functions? For context, I am using the perceptron as a pseudo SVM, so that I can classify datapoints.

I assume its 0, however based on tutorial I see people use 1. Why does this work. Also, is it possible to use a sigmoid type activation function then pass the output through a heavside function, therefore I can take the derivative of the sigmoid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is zero everywhere except at the branching point which is at zero since it does not exist there. This is so because the Heaviside function is composed of two constant functions on different intervals and the derivative of a constant function is always zero. The derivative doesn't exist at zero since the function is not continuous there (a jump exists at zero).

Numerically speaking, the derivative is set to be zero everywhere even at zero. This is problematic since gradient descent will not work because weights will not be updated and will remain the same from the time of initialization. To make gradient descent work you will need a smoothed version of the Heaviside function. One possibility is simply the sigmoid function.

About the second question, yes you can define a custom function with a custom gradient in many frameworks such as TensorFlow. You can set the output to be the Heaviside function's output and the gradient to be the sigmoid's function gradient.